# What mathematical structure best entails self-modifying programs?

Tags: computer-science, computability

1. If a program description can be represented as a sequence, then what is the best structure to entail program descriptions which self-modify?
2. There must exist a relationship between the structure in (1) and recursive functions. Can you describe this relationship in detail, especially as it pertains to decidability (c.f. Rice's theorem)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on which features of self-modification you're interested in modelling, I think.

My immediate ideas for a formalism would be either to model a Von Neumann architecture with some appropriately simple instruction set, or to define a formal semantics for some kind of idealized Lisp with some reflection features.

In the first case, the representation of a program would be a sequence denoting the content of the memory before the program begins to run (and possibly self-modify). By convention, input to the program would be placed immediately after itself.

In the second, a program could potentially just be an s-expression that the machine starts to evaluate. Because of reflection, it could start by defining some functions if it wants to, and later call them.

Neither of these options properly extend the class of representable functions. It ought to be clear that any of the usual non-self-modifying models of computation can *simulate* these models, and conversely a program in either of the models may still *choose* not to self-modify, so everything that can be programmed in a more usual model can still be programmed in one of these.

In fact, both of them easily seem to satisfy the modest requirements about enumerations of computable functions that allow things like Rice's theorem to be proved for them.

Comment: For context, the original question is to assist in formulating another. The goal is finding if Rice's theorem "extends" or "transits" to a recursive self-modifying function. A sub-question is what relationship recursive functions share with self-modifying code, which I may now post. Resuming: the sketch above was to find a mapping between a well-defined structure that entails self-modifying programs in order to show that Rice's theorem still applies under recursion. Apologies for the vagueness of the language.

Comment: To be more clear on my part: I am asking if either sets or sequences or powersets (or some other unknown) are best to entail what would be an infinite, possibly uncountable, set of permutations of a program that is capable of unrestricted self-modification.

Comment: In that case, I think there are two main points to make: (a) the decision power of self-modifying programs is exactly the same as the decision power of ordinary Turing machines. In one direction, a Turing machine can simulate the execution of a self-modifying program, simply by keeping the current text of the program on the tape and interpreting that as it goes along. In the other direction, a self-modifying program can simulate a Turing machine.

Comment: (b) Rice's theorem holds for self-modifying programs too. Specifically, if you claim to have an algorithm that decides some nontrivial extensional property of self-modifying program, I can use it to decide the same property of Turing machines, just by constructing a self-modifying program that simulates whichever Turing machine I'm interesting in, and running your algorithm on that. So Rice's theorem for Turing machines implies the same theorem for self-modifying programs.

Comment: (c) Not related to your main goal, but: At any point through the execution of a self-modifying program it has only made finitely many modifications _yet_. So the state of the program with its modifications at any point in time has a finite description. This means that there are only countably many possible states to consider.